# cordova - How to disable orientation upside down for ios?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, orientation

In my app(ionic + cordova) i set orientation for portrait, but when i open xcode to build, the option updside down is enable. how can i disable upside down in my config.xml?

my config.xml

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

So it's a combination of the `config.xml` file and `XCODE` settings.

In the `config.xml` file you'll need to add the following line right before the closing `</widget>` tag

`<preference name="Orientation" value="default" />`

[image]

Then inside of Xcode need to disable the `Upside Down` option under the `Device Orientation` settings.

[image]

Then you will have to delete the `platforms` directory then rebuild the apps so that the change will take.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your config.xml to: `<preference name="orientation" value="default" />`

Then at the platform level for iOS change your preference value to "portrait" via: `<preference name="orientation" value="default" />`

[Config Ref](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/)

Default: default

Allowed values: 
default, landscape, portrait.

This allows you to lock orientation and prevent the interface from rotating in response to changes in orientation.

NOTE: The default value means Cordova will strip the orientation preference entry from the platform's manifest/configuration file allowing the platform to fallback to its default behavior. For iOS, to specify both portrait & landscape mode you would use the platform specific value 'all'.

I had the opposite problem then solved it by changing this. I hope this helps!

Comment: Setting `<preference name="orientation" value="default" />` inside the iOS platform level will activate `Portrait` and `Landscape (Left/Right)`.
I can't find a solution to disable `upside down` with Cordova so I uncheck the box in Xcode. To open your project in Xcode use `open -a Xcode platforms/ios`.

Comment: Tried this solution. Still I need to open Xcode to disable upside down option.

Answer (score 0):

You can't untick iOS "up-side-down" by config file.

But you can use screen-orientation plugin to control it.
([website](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation))

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that is working for my projects.
With the installed Cordova plugin `cordova-custom-config` you can overwrite the `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations`-Setting with the following code **inside** of the `<platform name="ios">`:

```
<custom-config-file mode="replace" parent="UISupportedInterfaceOrientations" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
</custom-config-file>
```

Important is the parameter `mode="replace"`
The Key is of type Array and will be merged by default.

**Outside** the platform-tags you can set the default `<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />`. This will be used for Android and woont allow upside down there.

Answer (score 0):

The only and better way to do that is, simply install cordova-plugin-screen-orientation plugin in your project.
And in the `ionic.Platform.ready(function() {})` use the following code:

```
if (window.cordova && cordova.plugins) {
    cordova.plugins.screenorientation.setOrientation('portrait-primary');
}
```

I also had the same issue, which was causing iPhone SE to change orientation upside-down, and this code fixed it for me.